# Adapting Amazon-Redshift query computing average to query creating list of elements

Tags: database, list, amazon-redshift, average

I am not very familiar with the syntax of Amazon Redshift so my co-worker helped me write a query to compute the average of a column of numbers. I am not very familiar with the syntax and I want to adapt it to create a list containing all the numbers instead.

The list I want to create is a list of elements that is embedded in joins which makes the operation more complicated. The query that my coworker helped me write is the following:

```
  ''' --- Query written with co-worker's help
     SELECT  LOWER(some_query_query) as query,
             AVG(n_results::FLOAT)::FLOAT as 
             n_results_avg,
             count(*) as data_count
     from some_field
     JOIN
       (SELECT
          request_id,
          some_id,
          count(*) as n_results
       from s_results
       WHERE type_name = 'tinder_match'
       AND time <= '2019-06-20'
       AND time >= '2019-06-19'
       GROUP BY request_id, some_id) as n_count
     ON n_count.request_id = some_field.request_id
     WHERE time <= '2019-06-20'
     AND time >= '2019-06-19'
     AND language = 'en'
     AND country = 'US'
     GROUP BY  LOWER(some_query_query)
     ORDER BY n_results_avg DESC 
     --- Current Behaviour: Returns a table with query, 
         n_results_avg, data_count as columns 
     --- Desired Behaviour: Returns a table with query, 
         list_of_name_match_results, data_count as columns
     --- list_of_name_match_results is a list containing all name 
         match results (numbers)
      '''
```

Actual results: Output table with query, name_match_results_avg, data_count as columns

Desired results: Output table with query, list_of_name_match_results, data_count as columns

Comment: It would be easier if you share sample data and your expectation.

Comment: please add sample data, current results and expected result. please read and follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example